# Filter dates in Excel based on different "Start" and "End" values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, time-series

I have a period of data in Excel with 10 minute intervals (Columns C in screenshot) along with a few different intervals were the data needs to be filtered (Column N in screenshot). I have been able to identify were the data needs to start being filtered and were it needs to stop being filtered (columns H and I). However, I am unable to filter everything in-between, ideally I will get a "Filtered"/"Not Filtered" message on column J for all timesteps according to the different times specified on column N. Is there any formula/VBA code that could help me here? I've tried a few different things but I hit a roadblock.

Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VblQS.jpg)

Comment: FYI when posting the same question on more than one site, it's polite to mention that so folks can check whether you already got an answer elsewhere...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a formula:

[image]

Comment: such a simple solution but yet effective! Thanks a lot!